# Battery drawdown

Tags: dodge, battery-drain, ram

I have a 2014 dodge ram. The battery goes dead after a few days of not driving.  Replaced battery twice. Checked for draw down and found a 2.3 Amp draw down.  My radio had stopped working a couple months ago. So I pulled the inline radio fuse it went down to .63. Is this normal or am I walking in the morning?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! 2.3A is quite a bit. I wouldn't know, but are there any other things attached through this fuse? Pull the power for the radio (disconnect the wiring), replace the fuse and see if there's still a big draw on it through the same circuit. If so, you may be barking up the wrong tree considering the radio.

Comment: Ok. I am open for suggestions.  I know nothing about how to fix this problem other than trading trucks and I really don't want to do that. So any ideas would be greatly appreciated